# Laravel 5.5 - Cant Set/Get data from sqlserver 2008R2 (always return 500)

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, sql-server-2008-r2, laravel-5.5

I have problem with my laravel and sqlserver. Recently no problem with php pod because Ive use this sqlserver on my yii2 project and it work well.

```
try {
    DB::connection()->getPdo();
    if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()){
        echo "Yes! Successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration.");
}
```

I also have tried db connection and it returned "Yes! Successfully connected to the DB: MyDB".

This is my controller

```
public function postsignup(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' =>'required',
            'email' =>'required',
            'password' =>'required',
        ]);
        try{
            $users = new User;
            $users->id = '15';
            $users->username = $request->input('username');
            $users->password_hash = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
            $users->email = $request->input('email');
            $users->save();
            return redirect('/')->with('response','register success');
        }
        catch(\PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

my model

```
 public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password_hash',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
```

this is my view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            @if(session('response'))
                <div class="col-md-8 alert alert-success">
                    {{session('success')}}
                </div>
            @endif


            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('account-create-post')}}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                                           value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email"
                                           value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control"
                                           name="password_confirmation" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

myroutes

```
Route::post('/signup', array(
    'as' => 'account-create-post',
    'uses' => 'UserController@postsignup'
));

Route::get('/signup', array(
    'as' => 'account-create',
    'uses' => 'UserController@getsignup'
));
```

[image: This 500 error always appear when I try to access the database.]

This code are used to my signup. First, user fill the signup input field then hit register button to save their data to database but I know something wrong with my connection with database because this 500 error not appear if I comment **$users->save()** . I also have tried to retrive data from database with   **$users = User::all();** and this 500 error appear.
I hope some one ever faced this error and help me to solve this error so I can continue my work. Fyi I already do debug everywhere so I guess my codes are ok.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error then there will be a reason for it, along with a log entry. Please check your logs to see what the exact error is.

Comment: there is no error recorded in log because its 500 (cmiiw) , thats why its hard for me to solve this one. fyi this is my first laravel project, tell me if I need special configuration to configure laravel with sqlserver.

Comment: did you migrate you schema?

Comment: for the user table?

Comment: Have you checked the log for your web server, as opposed to the Laravel log.

Comment: @madalinivascu , no i dont do migrate, because my database already exist with all record in it.

Comment: so you have the users table?did you enabled debug in your laravel documentation?

Comment: @madalinivascu for user table, I have id,password_hash, email that is set not_null by default so I only focus on this field for now

Comment: did you mean in config/app.php ? I just set 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true), in it. It record all error except 500.

Comment: @madalinivascu , yes I have user table, by the way thanks for your fast respond, I already stuck on this for 3 days

Comment: why are you setting the id to 15?

Comment: do you have a user with the id of 15?

Comment: @madalinivascu I ve tried to let it automoticaly set by db but not work so I want to try to set it manually, but that not the problem. 

I dont have user with id 15 in db

Comment: if you query the db do you get any data?

Comment: no, it also return 500

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: i dont ask how to debug it , but how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 days finally I know why this 500 comes out. I recently tried to check db connection with error handling and it returned success massage, but when I tried to migrate schema from database, my cmd stop to respond, I realize something wrong with my db conf in config/database.php

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => 'my_IP',
    'port' => 'my_Port',
    'database' => 'DbName',
    'username' => 'Db_Username',
    'password' => 'Db_Password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => 'pos.',
],
```

the problem is very simple -_-, **prefix contain "."** . I remove it and everything work perfectly. huh awkward moment, thanks @madalinivascu for your fast respond +1 for you